# Can explicit(bool) act on the length of a character literal argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I'm writing a custom string class that favors space efficiency above almost any other considerations. It has a small-string-optimization for strings of 6 characters or less and uses interning for anything larger. There's a somewhat cut-down version included below ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/C6TssY)).

For convenience, I'd like to have a converting constructor from string literals that is implicitly used only when the string literal is short enough that it fits in the sso buffer. For longer strings, I would like the constructor to be explicit to prevent it being used accidentally (because of the performance implications of interning).

In the code below, I expected the initialization `Str b = "not so short"` to cause a compiler error because the conditional explicit specifier expression is true. However, I do not get an error on any of the three major compilers. Note: the `Str a = "short"` initialization works correctly.

At least one "compiler" thinks this should work as I expected: the EDG front-end used by Visual Studio's Intellisense feature gives me a red squiggle with the error `no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[13]" to "Str"`.

```cpp
class Str final {
public:
    using value_type = char;
    using pointer = value_type const*;
    using size_type = unsigned long long;

    // maximum length of a sso string
    static auto constexpr ssoMaxLen = sizeof(pointer) - 2;

    // construct from a character literal
    template <size_type N>
    explicit(N > ssoMaxLen + 1) Str(char const (&str)[N]);

    // construct from a zero-terminated string (other than a literal)
    explicit Str(pointer&& rstr);

    size_type size() const noexcept;

private:
    // the only non-static data is in this union
    union {
        size_type integral;
        pointer ptr;
        value_type text[sizeof(pointer)];
    };

    // index of the sso data and size in the text member when using sso
    // this assumes little endian
    static auto constexpr ssoData = 1;
    static auto constexpr ssoSize = 0;

    // masks for the different parts of the instance data
    static auto constexpr ssoSizeMask = sizeof(pointer) - 1;
    static auto constexpr ssoDataMask = ~ssoSizeMask;

    // perform interning of long strings
    static pointer InitLong(pointer str, size_type len);
};

template <Str::size_type N>
Str::Str(char const(&str)[N]) {
    // construct an empty string and return if length is 0
    auto const len = N - 1;
    if (len == 0) {
        ptr = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    // do interning and return if length is long enough
    if (len > ssoMaxLen) {
        ptr = InitLong(str, len);
        return;
    }

    // otherwise intinialize in sso mode
    text[ssoSize] = len;
    text[ssoData + 0] = str[0];
    text[ssoData + 1] = len > 1? str[1] : 0;
    text[ssoData + 2] = len > 2? str[2] : 0;
    if constexpr (ssoMaxLen >= 3) text[ssoData + 3] = len > 3? str[3] : 0;
    if constexpr (ssoMaxLen >= 4) text[ssoData + 4] = len > 4? str[4] : 0;
    if constexpr (ssoMaxLen >= 5) text[ssoData + 5] = len > 5? str[5] : 0;
    if constexpr (ssoMaxLen >= 6) text[ssoData + 6] = 0;
}

int main() {
    Str a = "short";
    Str b = "not so short";
    return a.size() + b.size();
}
```

Comment: After writing all that, I realize this is way too "clever" (a.k.a. stupid) and that I should probably have the constructor unconditionally explicit. I leave the question up anyway in case anybody finds it interesting.

Comment: I'm currious to know what *actual*, *real life* benefits you gain by using this over a plain, boring, `std::string`? Can you *actually* meassure any difference that makes a real difference? If so, in what situation? If not, why bother?

Comment: If your goal is to disable constructor if the string is too long for SSO, you should "simply" use SFINAE, not conditional explicit. I mean if someone writes `Str b("not so short")` what should happen then? Another question is why on earth should a constructor of a string-like class that accepts a c-string should ever be explicit?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The current test case I'm working with shows a difference of several hundred MBs of memory usage (sizeof(std::string) == sizeof(Str) * 4). Whether that difference is real enough in a world where we have so much memory available for so little money...

Comment: [mcve], please. 90% of this code is not relevant.

Comment: @r3musn0x I don't want to disable the constructor completely, I just want an error if it's used unwittingly. Because of interning, constructing a long string means looking at other strings previously constructed for one to reuse and that's more costly than one would expect of a typical string class constructor (O(n log n) vs. O(n) in my case).

Comment: @T.C. You're right, I should've done better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a short repro:

```
using size_t = decltype(sizeof(0));

struct Str {
    template <size_t N>
    explicit(N > 7) Str(char const (&str)[N]);
};

#ifdef OUT_OF_LINE
template <size_t N>
Str::Str(char const(&str)[N]) { }
#endif

Str a = "short";
Str b = "not so short";
```

As is, both gcc and clang correctly reject. If you define `OUT_OF_LINE`, both compilers accept. Filed [gcc 91429](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91429) and [llvm 42980](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42980).

Comment: Implementing the constructor inline of the class definition works on VC++ as well, thanks.